# Running pip gives a DLL load failed error

Tags: windows-10, installation, python, dll, pip

I am on Windows 10 using python 3.6.8

I'm trying to install something with pip but trying to run pip at all is giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\john\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\john\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\john\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "c:\users\john\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "c:\users\john\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 7, in <module>
    from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout
  File "c:\users\john\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I first tried a reinstall of python which didn't work. Then I tried googling which led me to try to install visual studio c++ 2015 redistributable which didn't work. I have installed every single version of the redistribuitable now and it still doesn't work. I have also tried another suggestion to add msvcp71.dll and msvcr71.dll to sytem32 and sytemWOW64. This also did not work. Python, Python Scripts, and Python DLL folders are all in environmental variables.

I've seen that having multiple installs of python can be an issue but when I run `where python` and `where pip` I get:

```
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

and

```
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe
```

Which is just because I have both 32 and 64 bit versions installed.

I have also tried uninstalling regular python and installing anaconda python which also had the same error given.

So I have no idea what to do now so some help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I am using it. No issue.There is a new version 3.7.4. You can jump into Process Monitor to find the DLL path.

Comment: I can't use 3.7 with the program that I want to use. I need 3.6.